# Ubuntu-builder no install candidate

Tags: dvd-backup

https://launchpad.net/~f-muriana
Apt-add-repository papa:f-Mariana/ubuntu-builder 
Shows no installation candidate 
I also updated the repo

Comment: You need to provide more details if you expect a reasonable answer. What are you trying to do? What are the results? What are the complete error messages? Etc.

Comment: It seems you haven't used `sudo apt update`

Comment: I used apt-get update and use apt-get install ubuntu-builder

Comment: If you examine the PPA page [https://launchpad.net/~f-muriana/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-builder](https://launchpad.net/~f-muriana/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-builder) you will see a button marked 'series'.  It appears that ubuntu-builder has not been updated since Feb, 2014, and the latest version of Ubuntu that there is a release for, is Ubuntu Saucy (13.10)

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the PPA page https://launchpad.net/~f-muriana/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-builder you will see a button marked 'series'. It appears that ubuntu-builder has not been updated since Feb, 2014, and the latest version of Ubuntu that there is a release for, is Ubuntu Saucy (13.10).  An image of that page is below.

Your options at this point would be to contact the package creator, or find the source files and compile the program yourself.

[[image: enter image description here]]

Answer (score 0):

The last version of Ubuntu that the author built their ubuntu-builder program was for **saucy**.

When you tried the `apt-add-repository` command, it created a .list file that used your current Ubuntu version as the repository that it should search for... I'll guess **xenial**... and the author has no such repository, hence you couldn't install the program.

**First...**

Your commands should have been... (*and the first command should probably be repeated*)

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:f-Mariana/ubuntu-builder
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-builder # this would have still failed
```

**Second...**

Now, if you wish to take a **medium risk**, and hope that ubuntu-builder still works with your current version of Ubuntu, you can fix it so that you can install it.

```
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*ariana*.list
* note the exact filename returned

gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/filename_from_previous_step
* change all (1 or 2) references of "xenial" to "saucy"
* save the file and quit gedit

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-builder # now this should work
```